# How to make a XML generator so it can be usable for all kind of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

What is the best way to create xml generator in ruby, but in a way so it can receive any model and generate xml by its fields and values?

For now i can make a Struct:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :age, :grades)
Person.new('Name', 21, [{:math => 5, :english => 5}])
```

and than pass that object to algorithm that converts it to a hash and recursively generate xml using Nokogiri Builder.

But in this way I have to make a hash structure by hand, which isn't good I guess. How to make this so that I can just instantiate objects and pass them to a function?

Comment: Rails has XML serialization built-in, try to call `to_xml` on your model (since your question is tagged with ruby-on-rails I assume that your actual object is a Rails model)

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question - what is the best way to create those objects that will be serialized to XML? Using Struct or actual Class? And after that, how to make hierarchy from that fields?

Comment: @11223342124 if that is your true question then the question is "primarily opinion based" or "too broad" as there are numerous ways to "create those objects"